# How can I use git-filter-repo to remove a large sub-directory directory before a historical date

Tags: git-filter-repo

I have a directory in my repo that has lots of large data files and a long history of updates.  I'd like to keep the last 12 months of history for that directory, but remove all the history of that directory before 12 months ago.

This means that a new commit will be needed that happens 12 months ago and adds back in the entire contents of that directory (as of that time) in one big commit.

I don't think using --refs will do what I want because I need to rewrite all the history.  I just don't want to remove the subdirectory in newer commits.